# Remove Triangulation in plot_trisurf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to remove the triangles or diagonals in between the wireframe of a trisurf. Tried altering the triangles by using the Triangulation method but it still doesn't work. Tried also setting the "triangles" to None but its still the same.

The code snippet for plotting is the following:

```
tri = mtri.Triangulation(y=data[:, 2], x=data[:, 1], triangles=None, mask=None)

c = ax.plot_trisurf(data[:, 2], data[:, 1], data[:, 0], cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True, edgecolors="black", triangles=None )
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting edgecolors to none?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to remove the edge entirely. I just want to remove the long edges of the triangles. So in output it should look like rectangles.

Comment: If your data is on a grid why aren’t you using plot_surface?